# error to try to pass parameter in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to call a function in my controller, I think than I pass correctly  the parameters but I obtain an error.

this is my function in jQuery

```
var usuario= $(this).data('usuario');
            var idea= $(this).data('idea');
            // llamada ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{path('votarIdea')}}',
                data: {user: usuario, idea: idea},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html'
                //success: change(),
                //error: noChange()
            });
```

in my url param I try to put this

```
url: '{{path('votarIdea',{'user': usuario, 'idea': idea} )}}',
```

in this case the error is that they don´t found the variable idea.

In the controller, the function is..

```
public function votarIdeaAction($user, $idea){
$em= $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
...
}
```

the error is this

```
Controller "Arca\PuenteBundle\Controller\DefaultController::votarIdeaAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$user" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one). (uncaught exception)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you misspelled type, and therefore wont accept your request properly?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{path('votarIdea')}}',
    data: {user: usuario, idea: idea},
    type: 'POST', // <--- here
    dataType: 'html'
    //success: change(),
    //error: noChange()
});
```

Comment: thaks @Jeff I correct then but I have the same error requires that you provide a value. have I to include the value in the url? I do it but dont work to

Comment: Try reading the value like this: `$user = $_POST['user']` - does that give you anything?